# Using vim extension on VS Code, but preserve original bindings

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I have been using vscode with the vim extension for the last year in my OSX, and now that I switched to Linux, the original bindings of visual studio code won't work when the vim extension is enabled. Is it possible to preserve the visual studio code bindings while using the vim extension? Am I missing some configuration?

Thanks.